# Trying to fix project with counting integer occurrences in an array with Scanner, the output is absurd

Tags: java

This is the program in it's current state, the output is incredibly insane and I am trying to see where the mistake lies. It is either the while statement or the nested for loop but I still can not come out to any solutions, any assistance would be amazing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = new int[100 + 1];
    int number = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ");
    while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
        numbers[number]++;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < numbers.length; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
            if (numbers[m] == numbers[n]) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        if (count > 1) {
            System.out.println(numbers[m] + " occurs " + count + " times");
        } else {
            System.out.println(numbers[m] + " occurs " + count + " time");
        }
    }

}
```

}

The output is something like this:

```
0 occurs 8350 times
0 occurs 8447 times
0 occurs 8544 times
0 occurs 8641 times
0 occurs 8738 times
0 occurs 8835 times
0 occurs 8932 times
0 occurs 9029 times
0 occurs 9126 times
0 occurs 9223 times
0 occurs 9320 times
0 occurs 9417 times
```

when it should be something like this:

```
1 occurs 1 time
3 occurs 4 times
```

Comment: this is your first mistake `numbers[number]++;` you don't store the current input

Comment: second mistake: your nested for loops do not make sense. you first sould create a list of distinct numbers and do the outer loop over this reduced list.

Comment: Third mistake: don't be so quick to call the output "insane". The output is a direct result of the code, which is produced entirely by its author - you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using two loops...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = new int[100 + 1];
    int number = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ");
    while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
        numbers[number]++;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < numbers.length; m++) {
        System.out.println(m + " occurs " + numbers[m] + " time" + (numbers[m] == 0 || numbers[m] > 1 ? "s" : ""));
    }

    input.close();

}
```

*** EDIT

Response to comment below...

If you only want to print numbers that have a non-zero occurance, just add an extra "if" statement...

```
for (int m = 0; m < numbers.length; m++) {
    if(numbers[m] > 0) {
        System.out.println(m + " occurs " + numbers[m] + " time" + (numbers[m] > 1 ? "s" : ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: This just prints out 100 numbers and sees how many times it has counted each one, but how do I make it so only the numbers that are used show up. So it would it would do:
1 occurs 3 times
42 occurs 1 time